# Zend routing: removing null parameters from the URL

Tags: zend-framework

If I have a route which is defined like this:

/event/:id/:instance_id/view

It appears in the URL like this when both parameters are set.

example.com/event/1/15/view

However, instance_id is optional, and therefore may be null, with the URL looking like this (as created by the url helper):

example.com/event/1//view

I want it to look like this:

example.com/event/1/view

How do I remove the unnecessary forward slash?

Comment: Can you please confirm if my below answer worked for you or it didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above question is for Zend 1 and the below solution is for Zend 2, so please dis-regard my answer.

<strike>Your route does not say 'instance_id' is optional. You can achieve this by doing this</strike>

```
'route' => '/event/:id[/:instance_id]/view',
```

It should fix the url problem. Also ideally, 'view' should be after 'event', if it is possible in your scenario.

```
'route' => '/event/view/:id[/:instance_id]',
```

Any fix text should ideally come up first in the route and anything optional last.

Comment: Neither of these route definitions works, both resulting in the resource not being found. If I restructure the URL to put the action before the parameters, then I have no need for the square bracket notation you were suggesting, it just works. However, I knew that already. Restructuring is not a solution for me. Thanks anyway. In fact, I found that using square brackets as suggested was not allowed. Sometimes the "id" parameter was considered to be "id[" as a result.

Comment: I tried it in my local machine earlier, using Zend 2 and it seemed to work. Can you please provide more code about how you have created routes and how you create url's, it will be useful to debug. Thanks

Comment: OK, well there's a lesson learned. I'm using zf1. Is square bracket notation for optional parameters for zf2 only?